# Event propagation, overlay and drag-and-drop events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I want to overlay a div over the viewport when the user drags a file onto the window.

However, I'm having trouble with the event propagation. When I set the overlay to `display: block` it appears to fire off a `dragleave` event and then another `dragenter` and then another `dragleave` again, so it's always in a post-dragleave state. Of course I call `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` on the event object, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The `console.log()` output when you drag something over the window:

> dragenter
> dragenter
> dragleave
> dragenter
> dragleave

The css. `#overlay` is set to `display: none` by default, but will show if `body` has the `dragenter` class:

```
    body {
        position: absolute;
        height: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #overlay {
        position: absolute;        
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: url(bg.png) repeat-x top right, url(bg.png) repeat-x bottom left, url(bg.png) repeat-y top right, url(bg.p
ng) repeat-y bottom left;
        display: none;
    }

    body.dragenter #overlay {
        display: block;
    }
```

The JavaScript; add the 'dragenter' class on `dragenter` and removes it on `dragleave`:

```
$(document).on('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('dragenter');
    $(document.body).addClass('dragenter');
});

$(document).on('dragleave', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('dragleave';
    $(document.body).removeClass('dragenter');
});
```

The html:

```
<body>
<div id="overlay">...</div>
...    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Scottux, that led me onto the right track.

Only problem was it also covered up the rest of the page, so none of the elements or inputs were clickable. I had to hide #dragOverlay by default with "*display: none*" and display it on this event

```
// Display an overlay when dragging a file over
$('*:visible').live('dragenter', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('body').addClass('drag-enter');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly the problem i was looking to solve for a couple of hours now ;)

but as far is i know jquery, $('*:visible').live() must be a pretty expensive selector. might there be another solution?

i mean the guys at imgur.com obviously found a way (drag a file from your finder/explorer onto the site and you'll see) but i couldn't reverse engineer the code to find out how they did it :(

Comment: I think it's a rather heavy handed solution also, but it's the easiest one I find (with time constraints on a work project and all). I've tried looking at the imgur code too and it's not something I wanted to dig deeply into.

Answer (score 6):

Your overlay takes up the whole document size, when you drag in, it fills up its space and your mouse is effectively taken out of the body and is now over the overlay. This triggers a mouseleave/mouseenter loop. To achieve what you are after, you may want to bind the event to a transparent overlay with a high z-index over the visible overlay which has a lower z-index. This would keep the event in the highest element.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/scottux/z7yaB/

Comment: This is the way to do !

Comment: Thanks dude, Elegant simple solution. :)

Comment: unforunately, this doesn't work for me, because I have inputs underneath the overlay that the user needs to be able to interact with when not dragging an item onto it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dropZone = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.eTimestamp = 0;
        this.showDropZone = function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            if (self.eTimestamp + 300 < e.timeStamp) {
                $("#coverDropZone").show();
                self.eTimestamp = e.timeStamp;
            }
            return false;
        }
        this.hideDropZone = function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            if (self.eTimestamp + 300 < e.timeStamp) {
                $("#coverDropZone").hide();
                self.eTimestamp = e.timeStamp;
            }
            return false;
        }
        this.showImage = function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }
        document.addEventListener('dragenter', self.showDropZone, false);
        document.addEventListener('dragleave', self.hideDropZone, false);
        document.addEventListener('drop', self.showImage, false);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? Posting code without elaboration can confuse others with the same issue.

Comment: This definitely needs some clarification.

Comment: im using this code to show the drop-zone when the mouse is entering the window dragging a file.
the object has a property .eTimestamp that contains the event.timeStamp and im checking if there are at least 300ms between both events to prevent multiple firing ( i had that problem )

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is instead of using **dragenter** use **dragover**

dragover
This event is fired as the mouse is moved over an element when a drag is occurring. Much of the time, the operation that occurs during a listener will be the same as the dragenter event.

Comment: Except that you can't detect when it leaves the drop zone.

Comment: This also causes the code to change the visibility of the overlay to fire repeatedly, which may (or may not) have performance consequences.