# Show overlay on 'dragenter' when dragging a file from desktop to the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, drag

i'm trying to achieve the same effect as on imgur.com (drag a file from the desktop to imgur.com and you'll see a cool overlay). already have a working solution thanks to this post: [Event propagation, overlay and drag-and-drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951051/event-propagation-overlay-and-drag-and-drop-events/9090890#comment11589866_9090890)

BUT: i find the solution rather unsatisfying. 
the problem is $(document).on('dragenter') gets fired multiple times when hovering over child elements. i was looking for an event that gets fired ONCE when i enter the viewport and ONCE when i leave the viewport so i could have a clean $overlay.fadeIn() and .fadeOut() on dragenter and dragleave.

i solved it with a transparent element that fills the whole viewport. i then call dragenter on that transparent element instead of on $(document). with $('*:visible').live('dragenter') i then show the hidden and the real overlay. $('#transparentOverlay').on('dragleave') hides the overlays. pretty hacky but it works (at least in safari/chrome/firefox)

but just the selector $('*:visible').live() gives me a headache...

anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

Try it like this, which works well for me. Essentially, it's imitating the `dragenter` and `dragleave` events, but only using `dragover`:

```
;(function() {
    var isOver = false, interval;

    $(document).on('dragover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        clearInterval(interval);

        interval = setInterval(function() {
            isOver = false;
            clearInterval(interval);

            /*** callback for onDragLeave ***/
        }, 100);

        if (!isOver) {
            isOver = true;

            /*** callback for onDragEnter ***/
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: This is the only solution i have found that worked perfectly...  im not sure if there will be issues with the setinterval and memory leaking, but so far, its worked perfectly.

Comment: Has somebody found a better solution since this time ?

Comment: Why did you write your answer in French in the first place? And then translate it to English?

Comment: A (slightly) better solution, based on this one, is to activate a `setTimeout` handler in the `dragleave` event. Store the timer's return value, and clear it on `dragover`. I've found that an actual delay is not even necessary, as the `dragleave` and `dragover` events are fired at the same time.

Comment: Posted my version below to clarify.

Comment: Genius solution. Speeding up the interval time helped me capture the drag better for the edge case in which the mouse passed by too fast.

Answer (score 3):

A more lightweight version of the answer above:

```js
;(function() {
    var dragTimeout;

    $(document).on('dragenter', function(e) {
        // dragenter code
    });

    $(document).on('dragleave', function(e) {
        dragTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            dragTimeout = undefined;
            // your dragleave code
        });
    });

    $(document).on('dragover', function(e) {
        if (dragTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(dragTimeout);
            dragTimeout = undefined;
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

May need to see more code/errors you're experiencing. Have you tried a simple boolean to check when your event has fired and limit the subsequent events?

```
var dragging = false;

$(document).on('dragenter', function(){
    if(!dragging){
        //DO SOMETHING
        dragging = true;
    }
});

$(document).on('dragleave', function(){
    if(dragging){
        //DO SOMETHING
        dragging = false;
    }
});
```